# How to do not allow a user to create another user with one role in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I have a user with the role 'manager'. This user can administer other users, so he can create users. In my system I have two other roles, 'representant' and 'client'. The 'representant' can create users too, but my trouble is that he can create 'manager' users. I want to allow 'representant's to create only other 'representant's and 'client's.

How can I do this? There is some Drupal module that treats this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the [Administer Users by Role](http://drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole) module might do.

Answer (score 0):

The [User Creator module](http://drupal.org/project/user_creator) appears to do what you're looking for.